# NG Bootstrap NG alert is not working

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I am following getting started guide https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started. trying the basic alert to work. it display the alert message not the style with bootstrap style sheet.

Any idea what I am missing here?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,NgbModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <p>
    <ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
      <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
    </ngb-alert>
  </p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-bootstrap` is only adding the *functionality* of the features, it's not adding actual styles. What you need to do is add the Bootstrap CSS as a dependency.

I created this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ftz67?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) with an example. In the external resources, I added the minified CSS URL and now the correct styling shows inside the application.

[image: External resources]

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Roy